# on click of iFrame container div

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to check if an iFrame has been clicked to hide a div that's overlayed over the top of it. I thought I'd be able to check if the div I placed around the iFrame has been clicked and then fire off my code, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code I have so far.

I'm using `wp_oembed_get();` to display the embedded video that goes in the iframe.

```
$('.fitvid').on('click', function() {
    if( $('.video-title').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.video-title').fadeOut('2000');
        $('.fitvid').addClass('playing');
    } else {
        $('.video-title').fadeIn('2000');
        $('.fitvid').removeClass('playing');
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

[EDIT]

As requested, the HTML I have is the following:

```
<div class="fitvid">
    <div class="home-video-container">
        <?php
            $embed = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_ht_pf_video_oembed', true );
            echo wp_oembed_get($embed);
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="perfect text-center video-title">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="format-icon">
        <span class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've noticed that if I click over the video-title div, it runs the JS, but clicking around the actual iFrame doesn't run it. So if I pause the video the title doesn't appear again.

Comment: where is your html code? It will be better if you can share jsfiddle link

Comment: Just to mention: if it is the only place where `.video-title` is hiding/showing and `.playing` is adding/removing, the whole function code can be simplified into `$('.video-title').fadeToggle('2000');` and `$(this).toggleClass('playing');`

Comment: Edited the code to show html. Unfortunately there could be more than one video on the page, thanks.